# Minesweeper implementation java

Tags: java, object-oriented, minesweeper

I'm writing Minesweeper implementation in Java. I have little experience yet, so I need some advices:

- about improving code, making it more readable and flexible
- about coding style
- about common mistakes that newbies usually do (I suspect I have some in my code)
- about code structure (for example, I'm not sure about where and how it would be better to store information about neighbour cells)
- about choosing best data structure for storing the minefield (currently I use simple 2D array, but I think it won't be suitable if I want non-square cells, for example)
- about optimization and rewriting some functions if needed

Cell.java

```
// represents single cell
public class Cell {
    public enum Type {
        MINED,EMPTY
    }
    
    public enum State {
        COVERED,UNCOVERED,FLAGGED,FLAGGED_DEFUSED
    }
    
    public int nColIndex,nRowIndex; // cell position inside the grid
    
    public int nMinesAround; // total number of mines in nearby cells
    
    protected Type type;
    protected State state;
    
    public Cell(int row, int col) { // by default cell is clear and covered
        this.nColIndex=col;
        this.nRowIndex=row;
        this.type = Type.EMPTY;
        this.state = State.COVERED;
    }
    
    public boolean isCovered()
    {
        return (this.state==State.COVERED || this.state==State.FLAGGED);
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//responsible for game logic
public class Game extends JPanel {
    public enum GameStatus {
        LOST,VICTORY,RUNNING;
    }
    
    protected Cell[][] minefield; // 2d array representing a minefield
    protected int nCols, nRows, nMines, nUncoveredClearCells=0;
    protected GameStatus status; // state of the current game (running, lost or won)
    
    public Game(int cols, int rows, int mines)
    {
        // start a new game
        this.nCols=cols;
        this.nRows=rows;
        this.nMines=mines;
        this.status=GameStatus.RUNNING;
        field_init();
    }
    
    protected void field_init()
    {
        // initialize an array by filling it with cell objects
        this.minefield = new Cell[nRows][nCols];
        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
            {
                minefield[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
            }  
        }
    }   
    
    public void plantMines(Cell firstClickedCell)
    {
        // randomly plant mines by generating random coords in 2d array
        // (like if it was one-dimensional)
        int nMinesPlanted=0;
        int nPos=0,nColIndex=0,nRowIndex=0;
        Cell currentCell;
        ThreadLocalRandom rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        List<Cell> nearbyCells;
        while(nMinesPlanted<nMines)
        {
            nPos = rnd.nextInt(0, nCols*nRows);
            nRowIndex = nPos/nCols; // get Y cell coord (row index)
            nColIndex = nPos%nCols; // get X cell coord (column index)
            currentCell=minefield[nRowIndex][nColIndex];
            if(currentCell.type!=Cell.Type.MINED && currentCell!=firstClickedCell)
            {
                currentCell.type=Cell.Type.MINED;
                nearbyCells = getCellNeighbours(currentCell); 
                for(Cell nearbyCell : nearbyCells) nearbyCell.nMinesAround++; // notify cell neighbours about new mine
                nMinesPlanted++;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    protected List<Cell> getCellNeighbours(Cell myCell)
    {
        // find neighbours of current cell
        // and add them to the list
        List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        if(myCell.nColIndex-1>=0) cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex][myCell.nColIndex-1]); // left neighbour
        if(myCell.nColIndex+1<nCols) cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex][myCell.nColIndex+1]); //right neighbour
        if(myCell.nRowIndex-1>=0) cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex-1][myCell.nColIndex]); // top neighbour
        if(myCell.nRowIndex+1<nRows) cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex+1][myCell.nColIndex]); // bottom neighbour
        if(myCell.nRowIndex+1<nRows && myCell.nColIndex+1<nCols) // bottom-right neighbour
            cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex+1][myCell.nColIndex+1]);
        if(myCell.nRowIndex-1>=0 && myCell.nColIndex-1>=0) // top-left neighbour
            cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex-1][myCell.nColIndex-1]);
        if(myCell.nRowIndex+1<nRows && myCell.nColIndex-1>=0) // bottom-left neighbour
            cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex+1][myCell.nColIndex-1]);
        if(myCell.nRowIndex-1>=0 && myCell.nColIndex+1<nCols) // top-right neighbour
            cells.add(minefield[myCell.nRowIndex-1][myCell.nColIndex+1]);
        return cells;
    }
    
    
    public void clickCell(Cell selectedCell)
    {
        // Trying to open a mined cell - the game is lost
        if(selectedCell.type==Cell.Type.MINED) {
            status=GameStatus.LOST;
            uncoverAllMines();
        }
        else 
        {
            // Clicked cell is clear
            uncoverCells(selectedCell);
            if(isVictory()) { // Check if there are any covered cells without mines
                status=GameStatus.VICTORY; // there aren't))
                flagAllMines(); 
            }
        }
    }
    
    protected void uncoverCells(Cell selectedCell)
    {
        // Uncover a clear cell. If it has no mines around
        // we also open all its nearby cells
        // Then do the same for their neighbours and so on...
        Stack<Cell> stack = new Stack<Cell>();
        List<Cell> nearbyCells;
        stack.push(selectedCell);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) // expand area around clicked cell while possible
        {
            Cell currentCell = stack.pop();
            if(currentCell.state!=Cell.State.UNCOVERED) // skip already uncovered cells
            {
                currentCell.state=Cell.State.UNCOVERED;
                nUncoveredClearCells++;
                if(currentCell.nMinesAround==0) // if ALL neighbours are clear, we open them too
                {
                    nearbyCells = getCellNeighbours(currentCell);
                    for(Cell nearbyCell : nearbyCells)
                    {
                        if(nearbyCell.isCovered()) { // skip already uncovered cells (x2)
                            stack.push(nearbyCell); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    protected void uncoverAllMines()
    {
        // If we open a mined cell, the game is lost
        // In such situation other mined cells are opened automatically
        // If some of them were previously flagged then they are shown as defused
        Cell currentCell;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
            {
                currentCell=minefield[i][j];
                if(currentCell.type==Cell.Type.MINED) {
                    if(currentCell.state==Cell.State.FLAGGED) currentCell.state=Cell.State.FLAGGED_DEFUSED;
                    else currentCell.state=Cell.State.UNCOVERED;
                }
            }
    }
    
    protected boolean isVictory()
    {
        // Check if we haven't opened all the clear cells yet
        // If it's already done - it's a victory. Otherwise we continue the game
        return (nCols*nRows-nMines==nUncoveredClearCells);
    }
    
    protected void flagAllMines()
    {
        // If there are no clear covered cells left then the game is won
        // Mined cells are automatically marked with flags
        Cell currentCell;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
            {
                currentCell=minefield[i][j];
                if(currentCell.type==Cell.Type.MINED) {
                    currentCell.state=Cell.State.FLAGGED;
                }
            }
    }
    
    public void restartGame()
    {
        // If user wants to restart existing game
        // we just cover any open cells
        Cell currentCell;
        nUncoveredClearCells=0;
        status=GameStatus.RUNNING;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
            {
                currentCell=minefield[i][j];
                currentCell.state=Cell.State.COVERED;
            }
    }
    
    public void setFlag(Cell selectedCell)
    {
        // Sets a flag on covered cell (or removes it if it's already present)
        if(selectedCell.state==Cell.State.COVERED) selectedCell.state=Cell.State.FLAGGED;
        else if(selectedCell.state==Cell.State.FLAGGED) selectedCell.state=Cell.State.COVERED;
    }
}
```

GameGrid.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

// Responsible for painting the minefield
public class GameGrid extends Game {
    final static int CELL_WIDTH=20; // cell width in pixels
    final static int CELL_HEIGHT=20; // cell height in pixels
    HashMap<String,Image> icons;
    
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
            {
                Image currentCellImage=null;
                switch(minefield[i][j].state)
                {      
                    case COVERED: { // cell is covered
                        currentCellImage = icons.get("covered");
                        break;
                    }
                    case UNCOVERED: {
                        if(minefield[i][j].type==Cell.Type.MINED)
                        { 
                            currentCellImage = icons.get("mined"); // cell is open and contains a mine
                        }
                        else currentCellImage = icons.get(Integer.toString(minefield[i][j].nMinesAround)); // cell is open and clear
                        break;
                    }
                    case FLAGGED: { // cell is covered and flagged
                        currentCellImage = icons.get("covered_flagged");
                        break;
                    }
                    case FLAGGED_DEFUSED: { // cell is open, mined and was previously marked with a flag
                        currentCellImage = icons.get("mined_flagged");
                        break;
                    }   
                    default: break;
                }
                if(currentCellImage!=null)
                    graphics.drawImage(currentCellImage, j*CELL_WIDTH, i*CELL_HEIGHT, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT,null); // draw current cell
            }
    }
        
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        // report grid dimensions in order to adjust parent's size
        return new Dimension(CELL_WIDTH*nCols, CELL_HEIGHT*nRows);
    };
    
    public GameGrid(int cols, int rows, int mines) {
        super(cols, rows, mines);
        icons_init();
    }
    
    private void icons_init()
    {
        // load icons that represent different cell types and states
        icons = new HashMap<String,Image>();
        try {
        for(int i=0; i<=8; i++)
            {
                // Current cell is open and has N (0-8) mines around (horiz., vert. and diag.)
                icons.put(Integer.toString(i), ImageIO.read(GameGrid.class.getResource("images/"+Integer.toString(i)+".png")));
            }
            icons.put("covered", ImageIO.read(GameGrid.class.getResource("images/coveredCell.png"))); // cell is covered (and has no flag)
            icons.put("covered_flagged", ImageIO.read(MainWindow.class.getResource("images/coveredFlaggedCell.png"))); // cell is covered and has a flag
            icons.put("mined", ImageIO.read(GameGrid.class.getResource("images/minedCell.png"))); // cell is open and mined
            icons.put("mined_flagged", ImageIO.read(GameGrid.class.getResource("images/minedFlaggedCell.png"))); // cell is open, mined and was previously marked with a flag
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace(); // could not load icon(s) for some reason
        }
    }
    
    public Cell getCellFromCoords(int x, int y) {
        return minefield[y/CELL_HEIGHT][x/CELL_WIDTH]; // get cell from it's coords
    }
}
```

GamePanel.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    final int ONE_SECOND=1000; // 1 s = 1000 ms
    JPanel pnlProgress;
    JLabel lblTime,lblMines; // elapsed time in seconds and mines count
    JButton btnRestart; // "Restart" button
    GameGrid myGame;
    ActionListener updateCurrentTime = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              int nCurrentTime=Integer.parseInt(lblTime.getText());
              if(nCurrentTime>=999) { tmGame.stop(); return; }
              lblTime.setText(String.format("%03d", nCurrentTime+1)); // increase time counter by one
          }
      };
    Timer tmGame = new Timer(ONE_SECOND, updateCurrentTime); // game timer
    
    boolean bFirstClick = true; // mines are planted after first click
    
    MouseAdapter userClickHandler = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();
            Cell requestedCell = myGame.getCellFromCoords(x,y); // get cell under mouse cursor
            if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me) && requestedCell.state==Cell.State.COVERED) // open cell on left-click
            {   
                if(bFirstClick) { // first click is always safe (impossible to lose)
                    myGame.plantMines(requestedCell);
                    tmGame.start();
                    bFirstClick=false;
                }
                myGame.clickCell(requestedCell);
                if(myGame.status!=Game.GameStatus.RUNNING) endGame(myGame.status); // check game result
            }
            else if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me)) myGame.setFlag(requestedCell); // set or remove flag on right-click
            invalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    };
    
    public void startGame(Level lvl, boolean bRestartExisting)
    {
        tmGame.stop();
        if(bRestartExisting) {
            myGame.restartGame();
            tmGame.start();
        }
        else {
            if(myGame!=null) remove(myGame);
            myGame=new GameGrid(lvl.nCols, lvl.nRows, lvl.nTotalMines);
            add(myGame);
            bFirstClick=true;
        }
        btnRestart.setText("Restart");
        if(myGame.getMouseListeners().length==0) myGame.addMouseListener(userClickHandler); // enable mouse input if it's disabled
        lblMines.setText(String.format("%03d", myGame.nMines));
        lblTime.setText("000");
        myGame.invalidate();
        myGame.repaint();
    }
    
    public void endGame(Game.GameStatus state)
    {
        tmGame.stop();
        if(state==Game.GameStatus.VICTORY) btnRestart.setText("You Win!");
        else btnRestart.setText("You Lose!");
        myGame.removeMouseListener(userClickHandler); // disable mouse input
    }
    
    public GamePanel()
    {   
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        lblTime=new JLabel("000");
        lblMines=new JLabel("000");
        btnRestart=new JButton("Restart");
        pnlProgress=new JPanel();
        pnlProgress.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlProgress, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        pnlProgress.add(lblTime);
        pnlProgress.add(Box.createGlue());
        pnlProgress.add(btnRestart);
        btnRestart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                   startGame(null, true); // restart existing game
                  } 
                });
        pnlProgress.add(Box.createGlue());
        pnlProgress.add(lblMines);
        add(pnlProgress);
        startGame(Level.arrPredefinedLevels[0],false); // "Beginner" level is default
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);  
    }  
}
```

GameParamsWindow.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class GameParamsWindow extends JDialog {
    JComboBox<Level> cbDifficulty;
    JLabel lblDifficulty,lblCols,lblRows,lblMines;
    JNumericTextField txtCols,txtRows,txtMines;
    JButton btnStart;
    JPanel pnlCommon,pnlBasic,pnlCustomize;
    JFrame frmParent;
    boolean bCancelled=false;
    
    public class JNumericTextField extends JTextField {
        
        JNumericTextField(int nMaxLength)
        {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,20));
            AbstractDocument doc=(AbstractDocument) getDocument();
            addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                ((JNumericTextField)e.getSource()).selectAll();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
                public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int len,
                        String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
                        // JNumericTextField allows only digits
                        String sNumericOnly=str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                        super.replace(fb, offset,len, sNumericOnly ,a);
                        // restrict text length
                        if(doc.getLength()>nMaxLength) doc.replace(0, doc.getLength(), doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()).substring(0,nMaxLength),a);
                }
            });
        }
        
        public int getNumber()
        {
            // get integer from JNumericTextField instance
            if(getText().isEmpty()) return 0;
            return Integer.parseInt(getText());
        }
        
        public void setNumber(int num)
        {
            setText(Integer.toString(num));
        }
    }
    
    public void setCustomValuesAllowed(boolean bFlag)
    {
        //(dis)allow setting custom values
        txtCols.setEditable(bFlag);
        txtRows.setEditable(bFlag);
        txtMines.setEditable(bFlag);
    }
    
    public GameParamsWindow()
    {
        initSettingsUI();
        setModal(true); // this is a dialog window
    }
    
    Level showDialog(JFrame frmParent)
    {
        Level selectedLevel;
        bCancelled=false;
        this.frmParent=frmParent;
        setLocationRelativeTo(this.frmParent);
        cbDifficulty.setSelectedItem(cbDifficulty.getSelectedItem()); // refresh text fields
        setVisible(true);
        if(bCancelled) { return null; } // dialog was closed with "X" button
        selectedLevel=((Level)cbDifficulty.getSelectedItem()); // get selected level
        selectedLevel.setParameters(txtCols.getNumber(), txtRows.getNumber(), txtMines.getNumber()); // update level info
        return selectedLevel;
    }
    
    private void initSettingsUI()
    {
        setTitle("New Game");
        setResizable(false);
        pnlCommon=new JPanel();
        pnlCommon.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlCommon, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pnlBasic = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        pnlCustomize = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        lblDifficulty= new JLabel("Difficulty level");
        cbDifficulty = new JComboBox<Level>();
        txtCols = new JNumericTextField(2); // number of cols
        txtRows = new JNumericTextField(2); // number of rows
        txtMines = new JNumericTextField(3); // number of mines
        cbDifficulty.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Level selectedLevel=(Level)((JComboBox<Level>)e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
                txtCols.setNumber(selectedLevel.nCols);
                txtRows.setNumber(selectedLevel.nRows);
                txtMines.setNumber(selectedLevel.nTotalMines);
                setCustomValuesAllowed(selectedLevel.sName=="Custom");
            }
        });
        for(Level lvl: Level.arrPredefinedLevels) cbDifficulty.addItem(lvl); // push predefined levels to combobox
        lblCols = new JLabel("Columns:");
        lblRows = new JLabel("Rows:");
        lblMines = new JLabel("Mines:");
        btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false); // "Start" button is pressed - dialog should be closed
                // Now parent window will get the selected level and we are ready to start the game
            }
        }); 
        pnlBasic.add(lblDifficulty);
        pnlBasic.add(cbDifficulty);
        pnlBasic.add(btnStart);
        pnlCustomize.add(lblCols);
        pnlCustomize.add(txtCols);
        pnlCustomize.add(lblRows);
        pnlCustomize.add(txtRows);
        pnlCustomize.add(lblMines);
        pnlCustomize.add(txtMines);
        pnlCommon.add(pnlBasic);
        pnlCommon.add(pnlCustomize);
        add(pnlCommon);
        pack();
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnStart);
        addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
              @Override
              public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                bCancelled=true; // "X" button was clicked
                // Dialog is cancelled and game won't be started
              }
              
              @Override
              public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we)
              {
                // if dialog is activated - make it's parent visible too
                  frmParent.setVisible(true); 
              }
            } );
    }
}
```

Level.java

```
public class Level {
    static Level[] arrPredefinedLevels = {
        new Level("Beginner",9,9,10),
        new Level("Medium", 16,16,40),
        new Level("Expert", 30,16,99),
        new Level("Custom", 9,9,10)
    };
    
    String sName;
    public int nCols,nRows,nTotalMines;
    final private int MIN_ROWS=9,MAX_ROWS=30,MIN_COLS=9,MAX_COLS=24,MIN_MINES=10; // limits
        
    Level(String name, int cols,int rows, int mines)
    {
        sName=name;
        setParameters(cols,rows,mines);
    }
    
    public void setParameters(int cols,int rows, int mines)
    {   
        // Assign values and make sure they aren't out of range (otherwise correct them)
        nCols=cols;
        nRows=rows;
        nTotalMines=mines;
        if(nCols<MIN_COLS) nCols=MIN_COLS;
        else if(nCols>MAX_COLS) nCols=MAX_COLS;
        if(nRows<MIN_ROWS) nRows=MIN_ROWS;
        else if(nRows>MAX_ROWS) nRows=MAX_ROWS;
        if(nTotalMines<MIN_MINES) nTotalMines=MIN_MINES;
        else if(nTotalMines>(nRows-1)*(nCols-1)) nTotalMines=(nRows-1)*(nCols-1);
    }
        
    public String toString() { return sName; }
}
```

MainWindow.java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class MainWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    GamePanel pnlGameUI=new GamePanel();
    GameParamsWindow dlgNewGame = new GameParamsWindow();
    static Image appIcon;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    appIcon=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/appIcon.png"));
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Minesweeper");
        frame.setIconImage(appIcon);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        JMenuBar tbMenu = new JMenuBar();
        tbMenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,0,0));
        JMenu mnuGame = new JMenu ("Game");
        JMenu mnuAbout = new JMenu ("About");
        JMenuItem itemNewGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        JMenuItem itemExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        itemNewGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                Level lvlChosen = dlgNewGame.showDialog(frame);
                if(lvlChosen!=null) // if dialog was just closed with "X" button - do nothing
                {
                    pnlGameUI.startGame(lvlChosen, false); // start a new game (level was set inside the dialog)
                    frame.pack();
                }
            }
        });
        itemExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mnuAbout.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {   
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Minesweeper 1.0, 2021",
                        "About",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,new ImageIcon(appIcon));
            }
        });
        mnuGame.add(itemNewGame);
        mnuGame.add(itemExit);
        tbMenu.add(mnuGame);
        tbMenu.add(mnuAbout);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tbMenu);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pnlGameUI);
        frame.pack();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very nice piece of code, thank you very musch for sharing your work with us!

i tried to list the issued order by severity.

### segregation of concerns / composition over inheritance / MVC

Your displaying class `GameGrid` **extends** from `Game`. That violates all principles in different ways. It would be easy to **increase loose coupling** by defining an interface in the game that provides all content, that needs to be drawn.

```
interface ContentProvider{
    Set<Cell> getMinefield(); 
}
```

assuming `Cell` provides a method `getLocation()`.

The purpose of `GameGrid` is to paint a Minefiled (a `Set<Cell>`), so you should give it a proper name.

And since `paint` is very specific on `java.awt...` and you treat it as a component (see `GamePanel`: `GameGrid.invalidate();` and `GameGrid.repaint();`) it **should be** a component. (i think your legacy annotations (`@Override getPrefferedSize()`) - even though there is no proper super class) show, that you already had this idea, btw, remove them or change hierarchy towards component).

### complexity / object orientated design / testability

these three issues go hand in hand. Lots of your code is complex to read and it would help to create methods to simplify the code - and increase testability. its easier to test small methods rather than the whole class.

unluckily the complexity is distributed, so i can only pick some examples in detail.

**example: GameGrid.paint(Graphics graphics)**

```
paint(Graphics graphics){
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
        ...
            //ok, here we should break complexity:
            Cell cell = minefield[i][j];
            paintCell(cell, graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

stop complexity by calling a method `paintCell` on `Cell` level.

**example: Game.uncoverCells(Cell selectedCell)**

```
protected void uncoverCells(Cell selectedCell){
    // Uncover a clear cell. If it has no mines around
    // we also open all its nearby cells
    // Then do the same for their neighbours and so on...
    Stack<Cell> stack = new Stack<Cell>();
    List<Cell> nearbyCells;
    stack.push(selectedCell);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {// expand area around clicked cell while possible
        Cell currentCell = stack.pop();
        if(currentCell.state!=Cell.State.UNCOVERED){ // skip already uncovered cells 
            ...
            //stop here
            expandCell(currentCell);
        }
    }
}
```

again, stop complexity by calling a method instead of digging deeper and deeper.

**example: Game.getCellNeighbours()**

here is a good example, where you missed an opportunity to use object-orientated code

instead of providing a method on the board to check if a cell is inside the board, you directly add the logic into the method.

In an object orientatded design our cell would have a `Location` instead of primitive coordinates. and a cell would know its neighbour locations

```
class Cell{
    private final Location location;//injected on constructor
    List<Location> getSurroundedLocations(){//...returns eight locations}
}
```

and our board would know if a location is inside the board

```
class Board{
    boolean isInside(Location location){//you know when its inside}
    Cell getCellAt(Location location){//again: trivial};
}
```

that would reduce complexity of your method (and increase readability strongly)

```
protected List<Cell> getCellNeighbours(Cell myCell){
    List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    for (Location location: myCell.getSurroundedLocations()){
        if(isInside(location)){
            cells.add(getCell(location);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** that would also reduce the duplicated code: `(if cell.nColIndex >= 0)` that is called 3 times, as well as on row index...

**example: primitives instead of behaviour (methods)**
what is see all across your code is a direct check on status. that is a poor design and adds complexity and violates the object-orientated design.

- here: `Game.clickCell`: `if(selectedCell.type==Cell.Type.MINED)` should be `if(selectedCell.isMined()){...}`
- here: `Game.uncoverCells`: `if(currentCell.state!=Cell.State.UNCOVERED)` should be `if(currentCell.isCovered())`
- here: `Game.uncoverCells`: `currentCell.state=Cell.State.UNCOVERED;` should be `currentCell.setCovered();`
- here: `GamePanel.endGame`: `if(state==Game.GameStatus.VICTORY)` should be `if(game.isVictory()){...}`
- here: ...the list is long

**Note:** one thing was astounding me: you did the oop approach on your method `Cell.isCovered()`. but here you violated the naming convention, the method does not return waht is expected: it has some hidden logic inside. that's no good idea, the method name should be adjusted to properly express the behaviour.

**example:Cell iteration**

```
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
        currentCell=minefield[i][j];
    }
}
```

since you use this code quite often, you should consider using a more proper type of data
`Set<Cell> minefield` maybe (or a map), and instead of accessing the array directly(see `Locaction`) you could get Cells with a proper method: getCellAt(Location location).

```
for(Cell currentCell: mineField){...}
```

### naming issues

some examples where you should provide better names for variables:

- `Cell.nColIndex,nRowIndex;` (aside from using a `Location` class), the proper names would be `column` and `row` (what is that **n** for? and the usage of `Index` should have been an alarm signal for unclean design
- a never-ending story:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){}
  }
  ```

  `i` and `j` should be `row` and `column`, or maybe `x`and `y` (my personal all time issue)
- `GamePanel`, where are the vocal? `pnlProgress`, `lblTime`, `lblMines` (and many many more)?
- `ONE_SECOND`  is really `SECOND_IN_MILLIS` to avoid misunderstandings.

### code convention

1. Method names are CamelCase, in java we don't use underscore.

- `field_init();` would be `fieldInit();`
- `icons_init();` would be `iconsInit();`

2. brackets are at the end of the statement

```
if(condition){
    ...
}
```

3. Always use braces for control flow structure

- `GameParamsWindow.getNumber`: `if(getText().isEmpty()) return 0;`

### improved programm flow

avoid complicated if/else structure, `Game`:

```
public void clickCell(Cell selectedCell){ 
    if(selectedCell.type==Cell.Type.MINED) {
        status=GameStatus.LOST;
        uncoverAllMines();
        //remove complicated else trail here!
        return;
    }
    
    // Clicked cell is clear
    uncoverCells(selectedCell);
    if(isVictory()) { // Check if there are any covered cells without mines
        status=GameStatus.VICTORY; // there aren't))
        flagAllMines(); 
    }
}
```

### provide tests

sadly i do not see any tests, i would apprechiate to see those too... in goodwill i think you just didn't post them ;-)

### use an IDE

the way your code is formatted shows that you don't use an IDE for Developement - or at least you do not use its fully potential. An IDE would help you to handle naming conventions and code formatting just by pressing one key.

### summary

the whole code is full of shadows of procedural legacy ^_ ^. whenever you do any primitive access you should stop and think: why do i access primitives directly, why do i not use a proper method?  methods are the heart of object orientated programming. the less you use them the further away you are from oop.

### update - details on oop cell

how could an implementation of the neighbour-hood relation look like?

```
class Cell{
    private final Location location;

    Cell(Location location){
        this.location = location;
    }

    Set<Location> getSurroundedLocations(){
        return location.getSourroundingLocations();
    }
}
```

```
class Location{
    final int x;
    final int y;

    Location(int x, int y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }

    Set<Location> getSourroundingLocations(){
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Location(x-1, y-1),
            new Location(x-1, y),
            new Location(x-1, y+1),
            new Location(x, y-1),
            new Location(x, y+1),
            new Location(x+1, y-1),
            new Location(x+1, y),
            new Location(x+1, y+1));
    }
}
```

```
class Game{

    Set<Cell> minefield;  

    protected Set<Cell> getCellNeighbours(Cell myCell){
        return minefield.stream().
            filter(c -> myCell.getSourroundingLocations.contains(c.location)).
            collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

### update - details on ["seperation of concerns"](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Separation_of_Concerns_SoC)

The Separation of Concerns principle is closely connected to the [Single Responsibility principle](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Single_Responsibility_Principle_SRP).

TL'DR
put Things where they belong to - as a car, motor stuff comes to the motor class, gear stuff to the gear class.

**part `Cell`**
A `Cell` has attributes and behaviour - and they should be placed within the `Cell` class. A `Cell` is responsible to hold (or not) hold a mine. Its state can be covered, uncovered, flagged (and defused?). That is greatly solved by your model (attributes & enums are very nice).

But to work with this `Cell` there might be **methods** required. E.g. for getting the state (not the `State` enum) of the `Cell`. So if you want to handle a click on the `Cell` you might want to know if this `Cell` is not yet handled. so you would provide the specific method `Cell.isUnhandled()`, which returns true if it is either/or, otherwise returns false;

Another Example: To reveal the board you might want to reveal each `Cell`, so there might be a method `uncover()` which does exactly that. it does *the magic of uncovering*, where it happens. And it does even handle the fact, that a `Cell` might already have been uncovered. this is called single responsibility and the method is on the right place (Separation of concerns).

Bonus: Your cell is very testable now. Invovoke `Cell.unCover()` on different `Cells` and see if the uncover behaviour is as expected.

**part `Board`**
a `Board`is responsible to assemble `Cells`. (no - it is **not responsible** to assemble `Cells` in **Rows and Columns** - Rows and Columns are never used on any action).

**SideNote**
You decided to abuse the `Board` as `Game`, something i'm not 100% in with. It violates the Single responsibility, a board is single/only responsible to manage the cells in a form of grid - nothing more, nothing less.

When you create or re-create your board have to distribute `Cells` on the `Board`. According to the *[principle of least astonishment](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-3-yellow/#Principle_of_Least_Astonishment)* i would expect to have a method `setup()` on the `Board` that does exactly that. Again, by doing the *setup Board Magic* on the Board we follow the Single Responsibility Principle and the Separation of Concerns.

If you think that the `Board.setup()` method does more than merely distribute the covered/uncovered `Cells` randomly over the board... then you might have an idea of a `BoardGenerator` in mind? In this case: do it! create a class `BoardGenerator` and add the `BoardGenerator` to the the Board and delegate the `setup` call to the Generator.

**Delegation example:**

```
class Board{//Game

    BoardGenerator generator;
    Set<Cell> cells;

    void setup(SetupParameters parameters){
        cells = generator.setup(parameters);
    }
}
calls
```

**already done nicely**
you did very well on injection the setup Parameters. That part was done good in your code!

Comment: Please, tell me, how should the direction object work? (for getting neighbour cells)

Comment: i have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. P.S. Should I use separate getter and setter functions for cell properties like "mined", "flagged", etc? Or it might be a good idea to store all the such properties in single data structure (and use single getter and setter function passing parameter name to them))?

Comment: P.S. I've just noticed that I have to rewrite plantMines too, but I have to pick random elements from set (that might be too slow). What could I do here?

Comment: i tried to point out that you don't have to write getters&setters, but instead write methods that provide the desired information

Comment: `return minefield.stream().filter(c -> myCell.getSourroundingLocations.contains(c.location))` will call rows*cols times `myCell.getSurroundingLocations()`. Each time building the same HashSet with 9 elements ?

Comment: @Holger see [beware of optimization](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Beware_of_Optimizations) - value readability (KISS) over performance... yes, imaging a field of 10000x10000 - it would take you ~3 years to solve it, when you are able to check one cell/second

Comment: @Holger point taken, you can create a final field of the surrounding locations, to prevent a new generation every time...

Comment: @MartinFrank, could I also show you changed source code, please? I'll update the post soon. I've tried to take your remarks into account

Comment: it is very important to **not change the current review!!** these are the rules of codereview.stackexchange. But i would be really glad to see your progress! If you have any updates, please open a new question. Its a good idea to make up a follow up question!!

Comment: your question makes me want to write my own version of MineSweeper^^

Comment: P.S. This: filter(x->myCell.getNearbyLocations().contains(x.location)) part is VERY slow even on 9 x 9 board

Comment: yes - i guess you are right, my eye was not so strong on performance ...

Comment: can you notify me when you have updates on your project, please?

Comment: Do you know is something could be done here? P.S. Yes, I'll notify you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131085/discussion-between-maxim-voloshin-and-martin-frank).